# How to receive the folder from FileChooserButton [PyGTK]

Tags: pygtk, filechooser

I'm trying to use FileChooserButton to get the path to folder selected by the user. I've read the documentation on FCB and I think I should use get_current_folder() but when I do that i get a global name error. As far as I know, get_current_folder() should already be defined in the FCB method, and should not be defined again.

```
    def on_fromdialog_current_folder_changed(self, widget):
    print get_current_folder()
```

This piece of code returns the following error:

```
NameError: global name 'get_current_folder' is not defined
```

Am I missing something? I've even considered scrapping FileChooser for a simple text filed where the user types in the path, but that would be pointless for the app I'm working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
def on_fromdialog_current_folder_changed(self, widget):
    print widget.get_current_folder()
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks man, I've no idea why I haven't thought of that myself.